# Detect React Server Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

Is there a way to determine whether a file or function is being executed as part of a React Server Component rendering, or a classic client component rendering (`"use client";`)?

Comment: may you give a final goal? do you want to reuse the same (utility?) function across server- and client-components?

Comment: yes I would like to provide a i18n helper which reads the context only when used inside client components

Comment: I understand that's not what your post is about but might it be possible to use [next-intl](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/03/internationalization-nextjs-13-react-server-components/) package?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, and I did not find anything about it, so I gave it a shot. As you noted in a comment above, both client and server components can run on the server... **however** they do not run *the same way*

So let's say you want to expose a component that does fetching. It would be faster if it can do so directly in a server component. However, we also want it to be compatible (and work) in a client setup, or earlier versions of React.

Here is what I came up with:

```js
export function MyFetchingComponent() {
  try {
    // This is forbidden in server components
    React.useEffect(() => {});
  } catch (e) {
    return <MyServerFetchingComponent />;
  }
  return <MyClientFetchingComponent />;
}
```

That is assuming client and server flavors as following:

```js
// This is how the data fetching happens, used in both case
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/json")
  return (await res.json()).slideshow.title;
}

// This is what is run inside a server component setup
async function MyServerFetchingComponent() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div>From the server: {data}</div>
  );
}

// This is classic client React
function MyClientFetchingComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(function fetchEffect() {
    getData().then(setData);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>From the client: {data}</div>
  );
}
```

*Note: Haven't tested thoroughly yet, [you can play with it in that sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/test-hybrid-component-n9xxtz?file=%2Fapp%2FMyFetchingComponent.tsx%3A2%2C1)*

Comment: My answer works, but it will run the `MyClientFetchingComponent` on the client after running the `MyServerFetchingComponent`, which is not best (here it would fetch on the server, then refetch on the client). Trying to figure out a solution

Answer (score 0):

The react team proposed that the bundler should take that responsibility.

For example you could use an export configuration like the following one inside your package.json:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "react-server": {
        "default": "rsc.js"
      },
      "default": {
        "browser": "./browser.client.js",
        "node": "./ssr.client.js"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now `import Foo from "my-module"`

- will load `rsc.js` only if imported from a react server component.
- will load `browser.client.js` if imported from a `"use client";` component for the web browser.
- will load `ssr.client.js` if imported from a `"use client";` component for the node ssr server.

Read more here:
https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0227-server-module-conventions.md#react-server-conditional-exports